# Libvirt storage volume info error after migrating

Tags: python, python-3.x, qemu, libvirt

While writing code that automatically chooses and migrates virtual machines using python 3.5 and libvirt. I got it working one way, but returning a guest to it's previous host fails (as of now I only have 2 hosts, but it should change in the future).

What I did:

1. Migrated a guest G from host SRC to Host DST.

   - Got the capacity of the source image on SRC using
     `conn.storagePoolLookupByName('default')
     stgvol = pool.storageVolLookupByName(stgvolname).info()[1]`
   - Created a destination image on DST:`subprocess.run(['qemu-img', 'create', '-f', 'qcow2', vm_image_path, size_str])`
   - Migrated the guest from SRC to DST:
     `dom = conn.lookupByName(domain_name)
     new_dom = dom.migrate(dest_conn, libvirt.VIR_MIGRATE_LIVE, None, None, 0)`
2. Tried to migrate guest G back from B to A using the same steps in (1.) But got 
   `libvirt.libvirtError: Storage volume not found: no storage vol with matching name 'guest-name'` on the line with `storageVolLookupByName`.

So it seems the image is not registering in the default pool during migration. Any thought on why this might be, or what can I do to fix it?